# Killing a PHP script that's using ignore_user_abort()

Tags: php

Some time ago, I was looking for a method to keep a PHP script running when the user aborted. (When the user closed it's browser). I needed this for some long queries to complete even if the user decided to leave.

```
ignore_user_abort(1);
set_time_limit(0);

while (true) {
    // Do queries
}
```

How would I kill the above script?

#### Update

The `getmypid()` function has been suggested to me. I now implemented the following:

```
ignore_user_abort(1);
set_time_limit(0);

// Get process id
$pid = getmypid();

$stmt = "INSERT INTO processes (pid, started) VALUES ('".$pid."', NOW())";
while (true) {
    // Do Queries
    if ($query) {
        break;
    }
}
$stmt = "UPDATE processes SET ended=NOW() WHERE pid='".$pid."'";
```

I can now query the database to see hwat processes have not finished yet. I'll know that these processes are stuck.

Comment: 1. by killing the process executing that script and 2. for stuff taking longer times to process you should take a look at a queuing system instead.

Comment: What is the event when you want to kill this script?

Comment: @arkascha Could you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @AkshatSinghal It runs some queries and then finishes. But sometimes I've got the feeling it just keeps hanging and my server becomes slow. So, I'd like to be able to manage the scripts that keep running somehow. Know how long they are running and kill them.

Comment: The script will still be done when it is done, just not when the user kills it by closing the web page.

Comment: You can kill the php process by identifying the process ids. but that you have to execute directly from terminal by logged in as a root user. Its a bad approach to give privilege for the www-data(php user) to kill the process.

Comment: We cannot see what's in your while loop. When the queries are done you would need to `break;` out of the while loop, if you want the rest of the page to execute after the loop.

Comment: Keep a log of the running scripts in DB/ file (add process ID when the script starts) and remove the entry when the script ends. This way you will know the running scripts and can kill then using sudo kill {pid}

Comment: Peter, did the solution work? If so, please post it as an **answer**, do not edit the **question**.

Comment: @Peter What do you mean by "could you elaborate"? Sorry, I thought that was clear to understand: 1. you asked how to kill the script. Answer: you can't kill the script itself, since there is no means for that in a typical web environment, you have to kill the process, so typically the http child executing your script. A process can be killed by sending it a `kill` signal, see the `kill` utility (its `man page`). Sure, that might not be convenient, but that is the only means. And 2. an alternate approach that is much more robust and scales better. I suggest you google the term "queuing system".

Comment: @arkascha I meant putting your comment in an answer. But I have the information I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can kill the php process by identifying the process ids. but that you have to execute directly from terminal by logged in as a root user. Its a bad approach to give privilege for the www-data(php user) to kill the process.

Best approach is, Inside the loop you have to check any flag stored in database in order to proceed, otherwise exit. So you can easily manage those database flag easily through code.

Comment: How would I know what processes to kill?

Comment: You can use getmypid() function in the running php process itself. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php.

Answer (score 1):

`ignore_user_abort()` has to do with halting the execution of the current PHP page when the Client *(Browser User)* closes their Browser. It will not stop your PHP code from executing. Therefore `die;` under a condition or changing the `set_time_limit()` can kill your PHP script.

Your code may look something like:

```
set_time_limit(200); ignore_user_abort(1);
include 'connection.php'; $db = db();
// do queries like normal not in a continuous loop
if($q = $db->query(/**/)){
  if($q->num_rows > 0){
    // do stuff
  }
}
else{
  die;
}
```